# How to generate diff between TIMESTAMP and DATE in SELECT in oracle 10

Tags: oracle, date, select, timestamp

I need to query 2 tables, one contains a TIMESTAMP(6) column, other contains a DATE column. I want to write a select statement that prints both values and diff between these two in third column.

SB_BATCH.B_CREATE_DT - timestamp
SB_MESSAGE.M_START_TIME - date

```
SELECT SB_BATCH.B_UID, SB_BATCH.B_CREATE_DT, SB_MESSAGE.M_START_TIME, 
to_date(to_char(SB_BATCH.B_CREATE_DT), 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') as time_in_minutes
FROM SB_BATCH, SB_MESSAGE
WHERE
SB_BATCH.B_UID = SB_MESSAGE.M_B_UID;
```

Result:

```
Error report -
    SQL Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
    01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
```

Comment: `to_date(to_char(...))` makes no sense if `b_create_dt` is already a `DATE`. Just use `M_START_TIME - B_CREATE_DT`

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract two timestamps to get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`, from which you calculate how many minutes elapsed between the two timestamps.  In order to convert `SB_MESSAGE.M_START_TIME` to a timestamp you can use `CAST`.

Note that I have also removed your implicit table join with an explicit `INNER JOIN`, moving the join condition to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT t.B_UID,
       t.B_CREATE_DT,
       t.M_START_TIME, 
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.diff)*24*60 +
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.diff)*60 +
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t.diff) +
       ROUND(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM t.diff) / 60.0) AS diff_in_minutes
FROM
(
    SELECT SB_BATCH.B_UID,
           SB_BATCH.B_CREATE_DT,
           SB_MESSAGE.M_START_TIME, 
           SB_BATCH.B_CREATE_DT - CAST(SB_MESSAGE.M_START_TIME AS TIMESTAMP) AS diff
    FROM SB_BATCH
    INNER JOIN SB_MESSAGE
        ON SB_BATCH.B_UID = SB_MESSAGE.M_B_UID
) t
```

Comment: There are simpler ways to compute the difference in minutes, using the right datetime functions.

Comment: @mathguy Your solution doesn't look that much better IMO.

Comment: Of course, "look" is in the eye of the beholder. However, my solution uses only one subtraction and a multiplication by 24*60. You have four different components, because you chose to take the difference of two timestamps instead of two dates. To me my solution does look better (not much, that we agree on, since there wasn't much to the assignment to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timestamp to a date using `cast(... as date)`. Then take the difference between the dates, which is a number - expressed in days, so if you want it in minutes, multiply by 24*60. Then round the result as needed. I made up a small example below to isolate just the steps needed to answer your question. (Note that your query has many other problems, for example you didn't actually take a difference of anything anywhere. If you need help with your query in general, please post it as a separate question.)

```
select ts, dt, round( (sysdate - cast(ts as date))*24*60, 2) as time_diff_in_minutes
from (select to_timestamp('2016-08-23 03:22:44.734000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff') as ts, 
      sysdate  as dt from dual )
;

TS                               DT                  TIME_DIFF_IN_MINUTES
-------------------------------- ------------------- --------------------
2016-08-23 03:22:44.734000000    2016-08-23 08:09:15               286.52
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - How so? *"I need to query 2 tables, one contains a TIMESTAMP(6) column, other contains a DATE column. I want to write a select statement that prints both values and diff between these two in third column."* That is **exactly** what my query does, except it doesn't pull the inputs from two tables since no sample inputs were provided. What did I miss?